# ASP.NET Listview jquery double click

Tags: asp.net, listview, click, double

Here's the top end of my list view

```
                            <asp:ListView ID="ui_lvJobList" runat="server" OnPagePropertiesChanging="ui_lvJobList_PagePropertiesChanging"
                            OnItemDataBound="ui_lvJobList_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="ui_lvJobList_ItemCommand"
                            OnDataBound="ui_lvJobList_DataBound" OnPagePropertiesChanged="ui_lvJobList_PagePropertiesChanged">
                            <LayoutTemplate>
                                <div>
                                    <table class="jobs-table jobs-table-body">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </LayoutTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr id="ui_jobId<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"JobID") %>" class="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StatusID").ToString() == "1" ? "jobs-row" : "jobs-row-started"%>"
                                    onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#b8e4f7';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#efefef';">
                                    <td class="jobs-table-JobId">
                                        <span class="no-decoration cursor-pointer">
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"JobID") %>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="hidden-ui-control click-me-to-edit">
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="EditJob" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"JobID") %>'
                                            ID="ui_btnListViewEditJob" CssClass="no-decoration cursor-pointer">
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"JobID") %>
                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                    </td>
```

...and here's my jQuery to handle double-click on any cell

```
        $("tr[class^='jobs-row'] td").dblclick(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().find("td.click-me-to-edit a").click();
        });
```

... I'm using jquery-1.8.3

The problem: the OnItemCommand is not firing when I double-click the row; there are more cells than I've included but I left them out for brevity.

I've tried with & without the preventDefault.

The dblclick function is being hit, I've run it with the chrome dev tools.

Thanks in advance for having a look. Let me know if I've not included enough of anything.

N

Answer (score 0):

Cracked It!

I changed the LinkButton for a Button (& made the appropriate change to the jQuery selector) & it works OK, now.